# Require.js backbone.js circular dependency tree hierachy

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

We have a tree hierarchy of stores. Each store can only have one parent, but can have multiple children. Our api returns its results nested like so.

What we would like to do is have a collection of store models, with children being another collection of store models.

```
[{'name': 'store_a',
  'children': [{'name': 'store_b',
                'children': [{'name': 'store_c',
                              'children': []
                             }],
                },
                {'name': 'store_d',
                 'children': [],
                }]
}]
```

we have a store model:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'jquery',
  'jCookie',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'require'
], function($, jQuery, cookie, _, Backbone) {

    var StoreModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            if(this.get('children') instanceof Array){
                console.log(this);
                var child = new require('collections/stores')(new StoreModel(this.get('children')));
                this.set('children', child);
            }
        }
    });

  return StoreModel;

});
```

This store model should get the fetch JSON (when we call the collection.fetch()), if the model.children is an Array then it should create a Collection from this and hence recursively go down the tree turning all Arrays of children, into collections. Once it returns from initialising the model it should set the current models 'children' attribute to the collection.

The collection is

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/store'
], function($, _, Backbone, storeModel){

  var StoresCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: storeModel,
    url: '/api/stores'

  });

  return StoresCollection;
});
```

Pretty barebones ('scuse the pun)

and the view is

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'collections/stores',
  'text!templates/stores/tree.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, StoreCollection, storeListTemplate){


  var StoresListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#page"),
    events: {
    },

    initialize: function(){
        this.login();
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'recurse');
        this.collection = new StoreCollection();
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
        this.collection.fetch();
        console.log('initialize');
        console.log(this.collection);
    },

    render: function(){
        console.log("in render");
        console.log(this.collection);
    }
  });
  return StoresListView;
});
```

What happens at this point is that I get a

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method '_reset'

in backbone.js at line 447.

I've also tried returning an object from the collection instead of a 'class', but this means that I keep adding to the same object and thus the recursive function that requires a new collections instance for each recurse doesn't work.

Should the above work? should I be able to do this?

Cheers

Mark

Comment: try adding replacing 'return StoresCollection' with 'return new StoresCollection' does that work?